# String + autoincrement number on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a `String` + `number` every time a value is inserted on database (the number must be autoincrement).
Is it possible to do in Schema? Or do I need to do that before the value's inserted on database?

`'question'` -> `String` followed by an `autoincrement number`

```
    var random = [{
        question: 'question1'
    },{
        question: 'question2'
    },{
        question: 'question3'
    },{
        question: 'question4'
    }];

    const RandomSchema = new Schema({
        question: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: does the string part change?

Comment: @e4c5 the string part will always be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoincrement fields in Mongodb, don't work exactly the same way that they do in an RDBMS. There is a lot more overhead involved. Never the less, creating an auto field is a [solved problem](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/). There is also a third party [mongoose-autoincrement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-autoincrement) package that make it a lot easier.

Extending, from that. Your problem is a solved problem too. Because

> the string part will always be the same

Simply use string concatenation to prepend 'question' to the auto increment field at display time.

Comment: Is there any solution for random generated string + autoincrement

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I implemented with [one of the approaches](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection) @e4c5 pointed out, without the use of a third-party package. 
Define add.js as below:

```
db.counters.insert(
   {
      _id: "itemid",
      seq: 0
   }
)

function getNextSequence(id) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: id },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}

db.randoms.insert(
   {
     question: "question"+getNextSequence("itemid"),
   }
)

db.randoms.insert(
   {
     question: "question"+getNextSequence("itemid"),
   }
)
```

After starting a mongod instance, do `mongo < add.js`.